# Matching data in R

Tags: r, for-loop, automation

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    temperature station.id  latitude    longtitude  sea.distance    altitude
1       18          S1           0.5        0.5              0.5        0
2       20.5        S1           0.5        0.5              0.5        0
3       18          S2           0.5        0.5              0.5        0
4       18.6        S2           0.5        0.5              0.5        0
5       21.5        S3           0.5        0.5              0.5        0
6       20.1        S3           3.5        2.5              1.5        200
7       18.3        S3           3.5        2.5              1.5        200
8       16.8        S4           3.5        2.5              1.5        200
```

Consider it to be tab-separated file which R reads by `read.table` and so on. I want to be able to **automatically** group values, according to the `station.id` column value.

Example:

For `S1` a variable like `S1temp <- c(18, 20.5)` to be created containing as string the `temperature` values.

The idea is that the data will often change and that change has to automatically detected. That is why, the above example won't do.

I assume that an `for` loop would be needed. What the arguments should be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using data.table (let's call your data.frame DF)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT2 <- DT[,list("temps"=paste(temperature,collapse=", ")),by=station.id]
```

The result is a table of unique `station.id`'s in the first column and a string of the temps in the second column.

Comment: I asked for a string with all values by `station.id`, which is helpful and so i guess you answered having in mind that

Comment: In what way is this not what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions - there are probably more elegant solutions.

Method 1. Make a loop over the values of the station.id variable, and make a new data.frame with these data, creating new variables in the current environment. The disadvantage is that may create many, many variables.

```
for(y in unique(df$station.id)){
    assign(sprintf('%sdf',y),subset(df,station.id == y))
}
```

Method 2. Make a list, using lapply, with the values of all the data for a given station.id value under the corresponding index.

```
results <- lapply(unique(df$station.id),function(y) subset(df,station.id == y))
names(results) <- unique(df$station.id)
```

Comment: your first solution creates a table containing all variables and values, but only for `S4`. How can duplicate the process for other `station.id` values?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. In my test case, the first solution creates a `data.frame` variable for each value of `station.id` (`S1`, `S2`, `S3`, `S4` - named `S1df`, `S2df`, `S3df`, `S4df`, respectively). `S1df` is the subset of `df` that has `station.id` equal to `S1`. Then `S1df$temperature` gives the temperatures for data-points with `station.id == 'S1'`

Comment: i will have to look at it more tomorrow, i am probably doing something wrong.. does `y` value changes?

Comment: Yes. In both solutions, `y` takes each of the values of the `station.id` variable, however each value is considered only once (by using `unique()`).

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to do this, is with the `plyr` package:

```
require(plyr)
station <- ddply(df, .(station.id), summarise, temps = paste(temperature,collapse=","))
```

This gives you the new dataframe `station` with `station.id` in the first column and a string of the temperatures in the second column.